# GroupBy and sum to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have two tables that are joined together like this..

```
var query = (from t1 in _db.Table1 join t2 in _db.Table2 on t1.CId equals 
              t2.ID where t1.DateAdded >= fromDate && t1.DateAdded <= toDate select t2)
             .GroupBy(c => c.Brand)
             .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Count());
```

This almost give me what I want, it return the number of different cFormat rows,
but I would like to it to be summarized on `t2.Qty` instead

If the data look like this...

```
Brand           Qty
Volvo           2
Volvo           1
Tesla           4
Tesla           9
```

My current query give me a result like this..

```
Volvo           2
Tesla           2
```

But I would like it to be

```
Volvo           3
Tesla           13
```

How can I change it to work like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your `Count` call to a `Sum` call, specifying the property that you want to sum on, like this:

```
var query = (from t1 in _db.Table1 join t2 in _db.Table2 on t1.CId equals
             t2.ID where t1.DateAdded >= fromDate && t1.DateAdded <= toDate select t2)
            .GroupBy(c => c.Brand)
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Sum(x => x.Qty));
```

Comment: Ahh, sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Count`:

```
.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Sum(c => c.Qty));
```